# EXM custom token use in query string

Tags: exm

We would like to use custom token in URL in EXM email
[image]

We are sending this email through EXM clientAPI

```
var customTokens = new Dictionary<string, object>();
customTokens.Add($"contactId", contact.Id);
AutomatedMessage automatedMessage = new AutomatedMessage()
{
                   ContactIdentifier = contact.Identifiers.FirstOrDefault(),
                                    MessageId = messageId,
                                    CustomTokens = customTokens
};
automatedMessageBus.Send(automatedMessage);
```

Above code is sending email but link which is added in EXM is converting into below code and not passing the `contactId` custom token value when we click on it.

```
https://hostname.com/sitecore%20modules/Web/EXM/RedirectUrlPage.aspx?ec_eq=rN44vKX49RHdqFvhTcbo97J8Hxy4RpN2FEI0CMHbX9wsf1K50cGBaGUMbr0%2bqGcVhTgw2fJovuZaHWAq1BVMCl%2fNaTfF3KJVOtXTqkYvRtuclqVTql21NSTNeJdHXchgB4zkot1gyAuUtU7IeYuvnGEU00J6EgIIUGtTEEoyS8w89jZ%2b6Fd7jbW2mS5HIuHlra5hj5TkG7BkpdAQSkfW6d17dHPy3WISVMBVTsAIRuVOtJsWtCxwBKNaP5IiRT1j0zd5OyMDXwnCjl%2bec0hnDK0Cf7swcBzBPOA8MJR7gQTepGmCHm7naka9ptxifgu6CC%2f0itgjipEdZR24zD6NgA%2f%2frVP402Q%2fc1IZ7s%2bzXBTOln8E4xJPTZZnBCFO%2f6R3ZxYoYeBwLR0WpUqcJeEUJ1lKA%2bSc7dV76mzFjlC5sSc%3d
```

When we click on above link then it is showing on browser link this :

```
https://hostname.com/thankyoupage?contactId=$contactId$
```

When we use `$contactId$` without adding in URL then we get custom token value.

Comment: Can you take a look at the post https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/17739/how-to-use-html-markup-in-customtokens-of-automated-messages, seems to be related to your question.

Comment: Thank you for sharing the link. However, it does not relate to my question.

Comment: @SitecoreMember did you check if the custom token is working if used without URL, I mean try using something dear $contactId$ and see if the token is getting resolved?

Comment: @RamanGupta yes, custom token is replaced with value if I use without url in email body.